# pandas series add fill_value from left side only

Tags: python, pandas

When applying an arithmetic operator via methods on a a pandas series or dataframe, you can pass an argument `fill_value` to specify how to handle missing values.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 2])
s2 = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan])
```

Just adding series `s1` and `s2` yields:

```
s1.add(s2)

0    2.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

`s1` is missing at `s1.loc[1]` and `s2` is missing at `s2.loc[2]`.  So at `loc[[1, 2]]` the `add` method produces missing.  If we instead use the `fill_value=0` argument:

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)

0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Which fills in missing values for `s1` and `s2`.

#### Question: How do I fill in missing on left side only?

I'd expect a result that fills in the missing `s1.loc[1]` and returns missing at `.loc[2]`

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this from the left side's perspective:

```
s1.fillna(0).add(s2)

0    2.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

From the right:

```
s1.add(s2.fillna(0))

s1.fillna(0).add(s2)

0    2.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

From both:

```
s1.fillna(0).add(s2.fillna(0))
```

which is almost equivalent to the orginal:

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)
```

This breaks down when both are missing.  If you want missing when both are missing, use `fill_value`

However, you can control each separately:

```
s1.fillna(-1).add(s2.fillna(1))

0    2.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```